# Run External application web browser

Tags: web-applications, browser

Please somebody advice me how i can run external application from web browser on client side

Like this:

```
http://ucp-anticheat.org/monitor.html
```

If you click one row on that link browser asks permissions.

This web page makes this with installed service on windows.

I dont know how to google it please advice me something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a client app that the client must install, and based on the protocol u can execute yr app based on that link.

same like utorrent opens magnets and torrent files

have a look here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx

Comment: Or you can make a browser add on for the client to install

Comment: Ok. and which is better way browser plugin or client side windows service?

Comment: it could be easier for you to make a browser add on

Comment: No i dont want easier way i need better solution :)

Comment: Then create a class with that functionality to register your url handler, and then you can use that class/dll in all your projects where you need your own url handler